# For Each Vba excel it makes just 1 loop

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I have 3 sheets, and i have to compare values of cells in the first and the second sheet and write differents in the third.

Here the code

```
Dim keyRangeSh1 As String
Dim keyRangeSh2 As String
Dim keyRangeSh3 As String
Dim cellSh1 As Range
Dim cellSh2 As Range
Dim cellSh3 As Range

rowSh1 = 2
rowSh2 = 2
rowSh3 = 2

keyRangeSh1 = "C" & rowSh1
keyRangeSh2 = "C" & rowSh2
keyRangeSh3 = "C" & rowSh3
For Each cellSh1 In Sh1.Range(keyRangeSh1)
   For Each cellSh2 In Sh2.Range(keyRangeSh2)
   'if
   'rowsh1 = rowsh1 + 1
   'keyRangeSh1 = "C" & rowsh1 
   'endif
  Next cellSh2
Next cellSh1
```

it makes the first round but it doesn't back to the second cell

Comment: `keyRangeSh1 = "C" & rowSh1
keyRangeSh2 = "C" & rowSh2
keyRangeSh3 = "C" & rowSh3` These are all a single cell (`C2`), so there is no loop to occur.

Comment: I increase keyRangeSh1: rowsh1 = rowsh1 + 1
keyRangeSh1 = "C" & rowsh1

Comment: But when you set the loop with `For Each cellSh1 In Sh1.Range(keyRangeSh1)`, `keyRangeSh1` is already set to `"C" & rowSh1` so your incrementing does nothing.

Comment: Also, your if block has no condition. So it should through a compile time error. An if block should be "If THIS then THAT". But Kyle is spot on, your loop starts off with one iteration to complete. If you want it to be able to increment itself within the loop then you need a WHILE loop.

Comment: Also, even if you increment keyRangeSh1, you are still referring to one cell. C2 is one cell, so is C3, and C4 and C5 and so on.

Comment: When you perform a loop, the `For Each` statement is _not_ reevaluated on the next loop. Therefore, when you loop around again, it is not changing the range. Not to mention, that would make an infinite loop since you increase `rowSh1` each time, it doesn't know when to stop.

Comment: the naming convention is pretty weird. doesnt read so well IMO

Comment: so is better compare the actual row and calculate the last row in the sheet and increase the actual until the first reach the last with a WHILE?

Comment: Better to work out the range before you start the loop. If you know it starts in row 2 and ends at a point held in a variable `rowSh1`, you could use `keyRangeSh1 = "C2:C" & rowSh1` and *then* `For Each cellSh1 In Sh1.Range(keyRangeSh1)`

Comment: Yes, definitely find the last row for use in determining your range. You may want to consider using 'UsedRange' here. It is worth noting that there are some instances where 'UsedRange" isn't completely correct (often sized too large), but it should work for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sh1") '<--| change "Sh1" to your actual first sheet name
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sh2") '<--| change "Sh2" to your actual second sheet name

    With Worksheets("sh3") '<--| change "Sh3" to your actual third sheet name
        .Range(Union(.Range(sh1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Address), .Range(sh2.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Address)).Address).FormulaR1C1 = "='" & sh1.Name & "'!RC - '" & sh2.Name & "'!RC"
        .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why set the value of UsedRange to its own value?

Comment: to get rid of formulas and leave only their result

Comment: Makes sense, I didnt think of that!

Comment: If you want to keep formulas, just get rid of that code line! And if it solves your question you may want to mark answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: I would, but I'm not the asker, I was just curious :).

Comment: @Alessandro95, did you get through it?

Comment: @Alessandro95, any chance to get feedback from you?

Comment: Hi, i didn't understand your code and i didn't get it. I solve the problem with a simple while, thanks anyway

Comment: You just have to follow the comment: to change the 3 names I used ("sh1", "sh2" and "sh3") to your actual worksheets names and then run it. nothing more

Comment: you may want  to try my code anyway, since you'd avoid loops and make all comparisons and calculations in one single shot